# Sharepoint form

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

My task is to implement in my SharePoint site a page with form where the users can add, edit and modify data. My question is which way is better to do that ?

Please for advice.

This is example of my form:

Code
Location
Location information:
Phone numbers (if applicable):
FFF:
Commercial:

C:
S:
R:
Fax:
Other:
Email:
General information:

Supported:

Freight:

Information:

Other information:

Comment: whats the purpose of the information, just store in sharepoint, update as required.

Comment: Information gone be different for each location. So the point is every administrator of location to modify that information

Answer (score 0):

Use a List where only "Administrators Group" will be able to modify.